# How to set the Adapter for the circular Scroll-able tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, infinite-scroll, android-scrollable-tabs

I am trying to set infinite view Pager(**circular Scroll-able tab**) using [Infinite ViewPager](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager) but when I tried to set the adapter

1.It work only from the end side (**last Position**).

2.It is not working on the start(**position 0**) side.

3.It repeat the last fragment when scrolled further.

My adapter

```
 private InfiniteViewPager pager = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

pager = (InfiniteViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
pager.setPageTransformer(true, new CubeOutTransformer());
pager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

}

My adapter class

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);
}
public int getActualPosition(int i){
return i < 5? i : 0;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
Fragment fragment = null;
i = getActualPosition(i);
if (i == 0) {
    fragment = new Albums();
}
if (i == 1) {
    fragment = new Artists();
}
if (i == 2) {
    fragment = new Songs();
}
if (i == 3) {
    fragment = new Genres();
}
if (i == 4) {
    fragment = new Playlists();
}
return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
String title = new String();
if (position == 0) {
    return "ALBUMS";
}
if (position == 1) {
    return "ARTISTS";
}
if (position == 4) {
    return "PLAYLIST";
}
if (position == 3) {
    return "GENRES";
}
if (position == 2) {
    return "SONGS";
}
return title;
}
}
```

I have gone through [Infinite Pager Adapter](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/antonyt/infiniteviewpager/InfinitePagerAdapter.java) and [Mine pager adapter](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/antonyt/infiniteviewpager/MinFragmentPagerAdapter.java)

but when I try to set the adapter inside another adapter I am getting an error in my adapter class.
where I am doing wrong and how I can fix the scrolling from both starting and ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set adapter like this

`MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(fragmentManager);
 InfinitePagerAdapter myAdapter= new InfinitePagerAdapter(adapter);
 pager.setAdapter(myAdapter);`

Also in your adapter change this code

from this

`@Override
public int getCount() {
return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}`

to

`@Override
public int getCount() {
return 5;
}`